# Altair boxplot interactive

Tags: python, altair, vega

Why interactive plots does not work in Altair for boxplots?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_boxplot().encode(
    x='age:O',
    y='people:Q'
).interactive()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Vega-Lite does not support zooming and panning for ordinal scales yet, follow https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4369 for updates.